# "Unanswered" questions not showing up in that list because of a single upvote

Tags: discussion

I have [yet another Shadowrun question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45959/can-physical-devices-be-hidden-inside-a-host-in-sr5), and I noticed it's attracting views quite a bit more slowly than most.  I didn't give it much thought until just now, when I went to the Unanswered Questions list looking to see if I could answer some questions, and noticed mine wasn't there.  So I went back to my question only to find the one answer it has - which doesn't answer the question at all, as I explained in my comment on that answer - has pulled an upvote, disqualifying the question from being considered unanswered.

I would strongly prefer to have the question listed in the Unanswered Questions list, but have no clue how I would get it back there.  Ask the poster that misunderstood the question to delete his answer (after folding my comment into the question, since it clarifies that misunderstanding)?  Downvote the answer to return its score to zero?  I don't think "wrong" answers are normally something we flag for, but I'm still reasonably new to the community, maybe I'm wrong and I should flag it?  Or should I just accept it and hope the question attracts an answer eventually without the benefit of being where most people looking to answer a question look?

Comment: apparently related:  http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/answers-that-do-not-answer-the-question  I assumed I'd see if the question had been asked before in the automatically generated list while I was writing the question, but here's a very similar question I didn't find until I'd posted this one.

Answer (score 11):

Downvote early, downvote often.

If an answer is a bad answer, downvote it. If there are no upvoted (as the sum total of their upvote) answers to a question, it goes back onto the unanswered list.

Comment: I primarily fear that I might have been unclear in my original question, so I should probably edit it anyway, but I didn't want to give a downvote in case it was more my fault the answer wasn't what I was looking for.  Will the downvote return the question to the Unanswered Questions list, though?  If not (or if you don't know), your answer says I must downvote you. :D

Comment: Absolutely, clarify your original question as much as you can. Downvotes are not permanent: you can undo them after the respondent has edited their answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm editing the question now, and already see the question back on the list where it will hopefully attract a quality answer.