# Why is my question with only a downvoted answer not appearing in Unanswered Questions?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

Before we begin, I'd like to say I've seen this meta question: - ["Unanswered" questions not showing up in that list because of a single upvote](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/unanswered-questions-not-showing-up-in-that-list-because-of-a-single-upvote/4851#4851) -
My question is related but different.

I've been wondering for a while now why my question on main  - [Recognize Firefly-esque sci-fi scenario with minimalist narrative d6 system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59302/recognize-firefly-esque-sci-fi-scenario-with-minimalist-narrative-d6-system) - isn't showing up in [Unanswered questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

From my reading of the above meta question it should be, as the sole answer has 5 downvotes at the moment, and no upvotes.

In a moment of paranoia I deleted my comment on the answer, as I wondered if a comment automatically showed some sort of condoning of the answer on my part, but it still hasn't turned up in Unanswered Questions. I also tried flagging the answer for deletion, but no joy.

I've also tried the different filters, ie "newest" and "no answer", but no show.

**Why is my question not showing in Unanswered Questions?** Is something broken? Or have the rules changed about answers needing to be upvoted to count as answers? Or something else?

Obviously I'd like my answer to stay visible in Unanswered Questions so someone can, um, answer it someday.

Comment: replicated here, not sure what's causing it.

Comment: I can reproduce it too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This has now been fixed, but I don't know how - my question is back on the list, and the number of unanswered questions has jumped from about 35 to 50 so I suppose I'm not alone.

Comment: @waxeagle This has now been fixed, but I don't know how - my question is back on the list, and the number of unanswered questions has jumped from about 35 to 50 so I suppose I'm not alone. –

Comment: And now it's missing again…?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Huh, yes, it and 11 other questions...

Comment: @SevenSidedDie and it's back again (Unanswered questions from 39 > 50 again)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And gone again...

Comment: Heisenbug. Or maybe they're fiddling with the code and we're seeing regression bugs.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So what can be done? Should I post a question on Main Meta? Are there any channels you can go through as a moderator?

Comment: Since this is marked [bug] it will get the attention of the staff, but there's no way to know what priority it will be given. We usually only hear anything once it's fixed.